# Shannon-Fano encoding

Tags: c++, memory, compression, dynamic-allocation

I've been trying to code the shannon-fano compression and I think I got stuck at a memory allocation. It goes up to the second iteration of the function and then crashed at

```
   nod *node=new nod;
   node->st=new nod;     
   node->st->st=NULL;
   node->st->dr=NULL;
```

This function is supposed to create the binary tree using Divide et Impera, but the first time it calls   *shannonFano(n->st,begin);*  it crashes. My supposition is that the allocation of memory is wrong.
    class nod
       { char *info;
        int *pondere;
        int val;
        struct nod *st, *dr;

```
void shannonFano(nod *n, int dim)
{     
  if (dim>1)
  {

 int begin=0;
 int end=dim;
 int b_sum=n->pondere[0];
 int e_sum=n->pondere[dim];
 nod *node=new nod;
 node->st=new nod;     
 node->st->st=NULL;
 node->st->dr=NULL;

 node->dr=new nod;     
 node->dr->st=NULL;
 node->dr->dr=NULL;

 while (begin !=end-1)
 {
  if (b_sum > e_sum)
      {end--;
       e_sum=e_sum+n->pondere[end];
       } else {
              begin++;
              b_sum=b_sum+n->pondere[begin];
              }
 }

 strncpy(node->info,n->info,begin);
 for (int i=0;i<begin;i++)
     node->pondere[i]=n->pondere[i];
     node->val=0;
     n->st=node;

 strncpy(node->info,&n->info[end],dim-end+1); 
 for (int i=end;i<dim;i++)
     node->pondere[i]=n->pondere[i];     
     node->val=1;      
     n->dr=node;

   shannonFano(n->st,begin);
   shannonFano(n->dr,dim-end+1);              

    }           

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, correctly format your code and explain better which is the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to do, but i see problems. According to your formatting, you want the three lines after your `for` loops to be executed each time, but only the first is. You need to add `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really see 100% of your code, and how it gets executed, so don't shout at me if I'm wrong, but this line:

```
int e_sum=n->pondere[dim];
```

seems suspicious. Where has this array been allocated? Is it of size dim? If so, the last element would be found at 
`pondere[dim-1];` and using the value at dim would cause undefined behaviour, likely crashing your programme.

Furthermore, your for loops are not followed by braces, so only the first line after them would be executed in the loop, whereas your indentation suggest you are trying to execute all indented out lines (3 in each case, I believe)

Comment: I do not intend to include all those 3 lines in for; I have just wanted to see them grouped.    pondere    is automatically allocated in the constructor i have not shown here. While debugging I have noticed that it doesn't pass the second iteration of    `nod *node=new nod;
     node->st=new nod;     
     node->st->st=NULL;
     node->st->dr=NULL;`